# Check a radio button using ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, radio-button

I may be missing something, but how do I programmatically check a radiobutton using ExtJS (v 3)?

The following doesn't seem to always work

var radio = Ext.get("myradiobutton");

radio.set("checked,"");

The radio is sometimes checked, sometimes not...

radio.is(":checked") sometimes return true, sometimes false

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just use the DOM?

```
Ext.getDom('myradio').checked = true;
```

Comment: Yes, this does work as a work around, but isn't there an ExtJs way of doing it ?

Comment: @Evan: I am curious, why recommend using the DOM directly instead of going *straight ExtJS*? I see from David's other comments that he's not using an ExtJS RadioButton, but my question assumes that it is an ExtJS RadioButton.

Comment: In the end (overly simply), Ext is just a wrapper around a bunch of DOM functions. If it's easy and it works cross browser, why not?

Answer (score 13):

I'd suggested using this function: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.Radio-method-setValue

```
var radio = Ext.get("myradiobutton");
radio.setValue(true);
```

Comment: I'm using ExtJS 3, which does not have that method

Comment: Ext.get() returns an Ext.Element reference, not a component. -1

Comment: Also, my radio is not an ExtJs form radio, just a normal radio button

Comment: This works as well:  Ext.getCmp('myradiobutton').setValue(true);

Comment: I tried both radio.checked and radio.setValue(true), only the radio.setValue(true) worked for me, at the same time it triggered the event change. I am using xtype=radio btw.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked using the `getCmp` and `setValue` functions.

```
Ext.getCmp('yourid').setValue(true);
```